# MvcSiteMapProvider "Home" button in menu not working onclick

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a menu generated with MvcSiteMapProvider using a helper for bootstrap and routing:

Controller Home:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Home", Key = "home")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Controller Other:

```
[Route("mypageview", Name = "mypage")]
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "My Page", ParentKey = "home", Key = "mypage")]
public ActionResult mypage()
{
    mymodel model = .....
    return View(model);
}
```

Helper:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
            {
                if (node.Children.Any())
                {
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@node.Title<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                             @for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                             {
                                   <li>@Html.DisplayFor(x => node.Children[i])</li>
                             }
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li>
                         <a href="@node.Url" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@node.Title</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
     </ul>
</div>
```

Layout View:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("BootstrapMenuHelperModel")
```

All of the menu items work perfectly and the dropdown menus too. They are all navigating to the correct locations. However the 'Home' button (first) of the menu does not navigate to index.

I have tried including index into the routing but that does nothing but break the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a url to a node without children and the onclick opens the submenu as standard on the nodes with children:

```
@foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
{
    if (node.Children.Any())
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@node.Title<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.DisplayFor(x => node)</li>
                @for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(x => node.Children[i])</li>
                }
            </ul>
       </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@node.Url">@node.Title</a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

For anyone who is doing this for the first time as I am, I also added an order tag to arrange my menu items in the order I wanted:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "mytitle", 
                ParentKey =  "home", 
                Key = "experiencevenuesandcircuits", 
                Order = 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of bootstrap. Since it is made to work with touch screens, AFAIK it is not possible to use a menu item that opens a submenu to navigate to a page. On a touch screen device, it would not be possible to tell when the user wants to open the submenu vs navigating to the location of the current menu item, so the only action available is to toggle on and off the submenu.

There are some [known workarounds](https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/issues/16), but I have not tried them so cannot tell you what the best solution to use with `MvcSiteMapProvider` would be. Suffice to say this is not an issue at all with `MvcSiteMapProvider`, so you might want to ask the bootstrap community what to do.